# How to use contains() with a char?

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to use the contains method on a string with a single character that i'm supplying. Is there any easy way to do this that i might not be thinking of? or do i have to go through a series of weird casts to get a CharSequence object?

Comment: Like this? `"abcdefg".contains(String.valueOf('a'));`

Comment: Or are you imagining `'a'.contains(...);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`contains(str)` is the same as `indexOf(str) != -1`, but `indexOf()` also have an overload taking a `char`, so use `indexOf(ch) != -1`.